# Compareing equal strings returns false

Tags: php

The first string is loaded from the database into a 'textarea'. In the second step i want to check if the text is changed in the textarea with the same text from the database.... everything is UTF-8 encoded.

I already read tons of similar threads, there where always whitespaces the problem. This is what i try:

```
$defaultTextblock = $this->textBlockTable->getTextBlock($textBlock->templateID);
$defaultTextblock->text = str_replace("\0", "", $defaultTextblock->text);
if(strcmp(trim($defaultTextblock->text), trim($textBlock->text)) !== 0)
{
    $textBlock = $this->textBlockTable->addDocumentTextBlock($textBlock);
}
```

And it still says there are not equal.... here are the var_dumps + xdebug:

The text from the textbox:

> string 'Bei weiteren Fragen, stehen wir Ihnen jederzeit zur Verfügung und sehen Ihrer Stellungnahme entgegen. Entspricht das Angebot nicht Ihren Erwartungen? Dann geben Sie uns umgehend Bescheid, damit wir uns sofort um ein Alternativangebot bemühen können! Bitte beachten Sie, dass sich dieses Angebot bis zur endgültigen Vertragsunterzeichnung freibleibend versteht. Ferner behalten wir uns Irrtümer bei Angaben zu Ausstattungen und Leistungsmerkmalen vor.' (length=458)

The text from the database(defaultTextBlock):

> string 'Bei weiteren Fragen, stehen wir Ihnen jederzeit zur Verfügung und sehen Ihrer Stellungnahme entgegen. Entspricht das Angebot nicht Ihren Erwartungen? Dann geben Sie uns umgehend Bescheid, damit wir uns sofort um ein Alternativangebot bemühen können! Bitte beachten Sie, dass sich dieses Angebot bis zur endgültigen Vertragsunterzeichnung freibleibend versteht. Ferner behalten wir uns Irrtümer bei Angaben zu Ausstattungen und Leistungsmerkmalen vor.' (length=456)

I really dont get the problem...
I know that the length is different but why?

Comment: see those two umlaut characters inside the string ? Best bet, the second string is not UTF-8 as you believe it is.

Comment: @Calimero thought first the same but if i write  if(strcmp(trim(utf8_encode($defaultTextblock->text)), trim(utf8_encode($textBlock->text))) !== 0) its exact the same result

Comment: The utf functions cannot somehow magically fix this. Dump both strings into files and compare them using a `hexeditor`. That is the only reliable way to deal with encoding issues.

Comment: @arkascha i did this and yes there is a different but that was expected if the length is already different. The question is how to solve this problem? I dont know how reliable the function is but 'mb_detect_encoding' says that both strings are UTF8

Comment: Forget automatic detection of encoding, it is proven and obvious that it cannot work reliable. You should consider it more a heuristic, not a precise tool. Simple reason is that the question if which encoding a text is in cannot be clearly decided in most cases. One example: _every_ string is a valid 8-bit encoded string, if you think about it. All the algorithms can do is reliably say that a certain string is _not_ valid utf encoded if illegal utf escape sequences occur inside. Actually the algorithms look at the first 100 chars or so anyway... Bottom line: you need to know the encoding.

Comment: @arkascha but i dont know where the happens. The DB is Utf8, the mysqli has uft8-charset, the html-meta has the utf8 attr. I use the jquery serilize function to send the form via ajax to save the 'textBlocks' i guess there is the problem....

Comment: @Tiega check the table collation perhaps

Comment: @Calimero i did its UTF8, but even if not i mean i read the value from the db and compare the SAME value again after it was in a textarea and its not the same anymore

Comment: @Tiega if the text comes out altered from the db no matter what, then this probably means it was stored like that in the first place. As you might have guessed that means checking the whole insertion code for UTF8 compliance and updating the existing DB data acordingly.

Comment: @Calimero Okay i found the problem, after the text did go through the textarea there is a '&lt;br /&gt;<br />' instead just '<br />' found it while dumping the text as  nl2br(htmlentities($data['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')).... what does this mean and from where does it come?

Comment: means you already used nl2br() at some point before that, thus the <br /> tag is already present inside the $data['text'] string, maybe it is in DB too.

Comment: @Calimero No i save them plane with \r\n in the DB. i now tried to remove all breaks before comparing and it works.... but this is not how its supposed to be because i even need to know if there are new breaks in the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that PHP is running under Windows IIS(what i didnt mendtioned) and the Database is MySQL. There are both using different ways to handle break-lines.

- Windows is using `\r\n`
- MySQL(and Linux) is using `\n`

Sadly the blockcode didnt showed that the text had a break-line in it otherwise some of you guys for sure had found the answer already. There was exactly 1 break-line and the additional `\r` are the difference '2' in the length